# How to perform equality match for documents of single collection using lookup in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, and I am trying to do an equality match, but keep failing to do so. I have a "user" collection and it has following data:

```
{
  uid:"1230"
  age:20
  Name:"Alex"
  gender:"male"
  interestedIn:"female"
}

{
  uid:"1231"
  age:23
  Name:"Neil"
  gender:"male"
  interestedIn:"male"
}

{
  uid:"1232"
  age:20
  Name:"Amy"
  gender:"female"
  interestedIn:"male"
}
```

What I want is to find the records whose "gender" is equal to the "interestedIn" of the current user and vice versa. i.e. when i am accessing as user "Alex", then the query should provide me the record of "Amy" only (as Amy's gender value is equal to the Alex's "interestedIn" value) and not that of Neil. and

When I am accessing as user "Neil", no data should return as there is no any user who is male as well as interested in male !

I tried to use the $lookup but its not working at all. And i am struggling to use $cond operator for this case. Here is my code:

// I am also using the geospatial functions (by hard coding the coordinates) but its not the problem here, and nothing is being returned.

```
db.users.aggregate([{
"$geoNear": {
  "near": {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [31.9686, 99.90]
  },
  "spherical": true,
  "distanceField": "distance",
  "maxDistance": 500,
  "query": {
    uid: {
      $ne: "1230"
    },
    age: {
      $gt: 18,
      $lt: 25
    },
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: "users",
      localField: "gender",
      foreignField: "interestedIn",
      as: "gender_docs"
    }
  },
  limit: 5
}  
},
   {
        "$project": {
          location: 0
        }
      }
    ]).pretty()
```

Could someone please let me know how should I do it properly ?

// My expected output when current user is Alex

```
 {
  uid:"1232"
  age:20
  Name:"Amy"
  gender:"female"
  interestedIn:"male"
}
```

My expected output when current user is Neil should be blank as there are no any other record whose gender is male and interestedIn is male !

Comment: can you add the exact expected output ?

Comment: Try `localField: "interestedIn",       foreignField: "gender"`

Comment: @Veeram Nothing happens in mongo shell after i tried the one you mentioned. Could you please help me out !

Comment: Can you just try the code with only lookup stage and see if returns anything ? The lookup code is correct.

Comment: @Veeram, the code works with only lookup stage, But i need to use aggregation to pull the users who are near to the current user by certain distance. how should i proceed further. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: how do you access it as user Alex ? :p

Comment: what is the name of the field where you store a users location?

Comment: @Alex, I have a checkin post (request) url, where I could access it as a current user...What i want is to pull other record ($ne: currentUserId) who have their gender value equals to the "InterestedIn" of current user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the aggregation framework and `$lookup` here. I expect you have the attributes of the current user (e.g. `interestedIn`) present in your app.

A simple query for your question would be:

```
db.users.find({
    "gender": currentUserInterestedIn, 
    "_id": { "$ne": currentUserID },
    "location": "$near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [currentUserLat, currentUserLong],
        "$maxDistance": 500    
    },
})
```

Where `currentUserInterestedIn` should be the actual value of the current users interest, i.e. `"male"` or `"female"`.

This assumes a users location is stored in a field named `location`.

Comment: I do not have "currentUserInterestedIn" field, Was there a dot operator missing in your code for value of gender? And I am using aggregation for the geospatial queries. I have added the expected output too!

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "dot operator".  You can use geospatial queries without aggregation, too. Aggregation would be used if you would like to count something.

Comment: your code has "gender": currentUserInterestedIn , but I do not have any key field with such name.I was guessing "currentUser.InterestedIn "...how can i perform the above query without aggregation ? Wont doing it other way hamper the performance of db ?

Comment: the same way you put some coordinates into your example query above, you would put the actual `interestedIn` value into my query instead of `currentUserInterestedIn`. It is just a placeholder name i put in to say that "the actual value goes here".

Comment: ok thanks, I will try as you said and let you know if everything goes well..BTW what about the performance of db if i dont use aggregation here ?

Comment: no, it doesnt hurt performance. you are not aggregating anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168758/discussion-between-code-reactor-and-mikezter).