# How to perform $lookup on specific ids in all matched documents in a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am facing a problem as I have reference IDs within collection A of documents in the collection B, Say I have two collections

Programmers

```
_id: ObjectID('1'),
name: "Ryan Dahl",
profession: "Node.js",
country: 01,

_id: ObjectID('2')
name: "Dan Abramov",
profession: "React.js",
country: 02,
```

and another collection
Country

```
_id: ObjectID('01')
name: 'USA',
capital: "Washington",

_id: ObjectID('02')
name: 'Russia',
capital: "Moscow",
```

I query all documents by their profession, and suppose "Node.js" fetches 100 documents from programmers collection like below

```
_id: ObjectID('1'),
name: "Ryan Dahl",
profession: "Node.js",
country: 01,

_id: ObjectID('2'),
name: "Stephen Grider",
profession: "Node.js",
country: 01,

_id: ObjectID('3'),
name: "Brad Traversy",
profession: "Node.js",
country: 01,

_id: ObjectID('4'),
name: "Matteo Collina",
profession: "Node.js",
country: 03,
```

Now I want to perfom $lookup operator on all the results in order to reference countryId in country collections, the **expected** results are as follows

```
_id: ObjectID('1'),
name: "Ryan Dahl",
profession: "Node.js",
country: {
_id: ObjectID('01')
name: 'USA',
capital: "Washington",
}

 _id: ObjectID('2'),
name: "Stephen Grider",
profession: "Node.js",
country: {
_id: ObjectID('01')
name: 'USA',
capital: "Washington",
}

 _id: ObjectID('3'),
name: "Brad Traversy",
profession: "Node.js",
country: {
_id: ObjectID('01')
name: 'USA',
capital: "Washington",
}

 _id: ObjectID('4'),
name: "Matteo Collina",
profession: "Node.js",
country: {
_id: ObjectID('03')
name: 'Italy',
capital: "Rome",
}
```

Now I know aggregation framework is used to produce a single document, and in the case of nested or deeply nested arrays, it works perfectly, but when it comes to use-cases like mine, I can't think of a way to apply aggregation framework only once and populate all referenced country IDs, I tried the following way

```
const allNodeProgrammers = await Programmers.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        profession: profession,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Country',
        let: {
          country: '$country',
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$country'] },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: 'country',
      },
    },
  ]);
  return allNodeProgrammers.toArray();
```

But it predictably returned only the first matching instance with populated countryID.

Couldn't find any SO answer on this particular use-case, applied basic lookup like in the following [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match-with-a-single-join-condition) but it returns only the first matched instance, and the closest was this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773548/how-to-perform-equality-match-for-documents-of-single-collection-using-lookup-in) question but it didn't address my queries. Should I first fetch all results and then loop through the array in order to populate country ID, or is there another way to approach this problem.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a mistake in the controller file as follows

```
res.status(200).json({
    ...allNodeProgrammers[0],
  });
```

Changing to the following fixed it

```
res.status(200).json({
    ...allNodeProgrammers,
  });
```